# How to disable checking missing params in object in javascript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I want to add tsconfig.json to existing react project. What i needed is type checking and intellisense in js/jsx files. But some files have ts2345 error with missing properties in type.

I trying to configure tsconfig.json file but with no effect.

i`ve got following error:

```
(property) param1: any
Argument of type '{ param1: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ param1: any; param2: any; param3: any; param4: any; param5: any; }'.
  Type '{ param1: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ param1: any; param2: any; param3: any; param4: any; param5: any; }': param2, param3, param4, param5ts(2345)
```

```
//testCall.js
import { request } from "./testSource"

const param1 = "ok"

request({
    param1 // HERE IS ERROR
})
```

```
//testSource.js
export const request = ({
    param1,
    param2,
    param3,
    param4,
    param5,
}) => {
    //some code
}
```

```
//tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

I want to make function with multiple callbacks but I also want to not init always all params.

Comment: Mark the params as optional using `?`.

Comment: this is not .ts file

Comment: Sorry yes I misread that part... you may be able to mark them optional using jsdoc, though.

Comment: You can also try using `// @ts-ignore` but I'm not sure if it works in a JS file.

Comment: You might also be able to mark them optional by assigning default values (sorry for many comments)

Comment: @ts-ignore nope - too many files to change, default values is option, but there is some other functions to add default params